# Can't create runnable file from project with NetBeans if it uses JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, executable-jar

I originally asked another question regarding the specific issue of not being able to create an `.exe` file, but after trying three different methods that gave me three different errors, I've come to the conclusion that the problem has something to do with the use of `JavaFX` itself.

Long story short, I wrote a small program on `Apache NetBeans 11.3` that uses `JavaFX` for the GUI. It has a class named `Main` that extends `Application` and another one called `Launcher` that does not, and whose purpose is to call `Main.main(args)`.

I have tried in vain to create a runnable file of some sort for this program using `NetBeans`.

Under the `Packaging` project properties, I ticked `Compress JAR File`, `Build JAR after Compiling`, and `Copy Dependent Libraries`. Under `Deployment` I ticked `Enable Native Packaging Actions in Project Menu` and `Keep JavaFX artifacts on Compile Classpath if not present by default`. These are the same settings I found in every tutorial, although the tutorials I found were for version 8 or older of `NetBeans`.

When I try the standard "Clean and build" option, attempting to run the resulting `.jar` from the command prompt returns the following error:

`Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found`

Along with a ton of other lines I can copy/paste here if it's deemed necessary. I've tried the solutions I found online, but none of them worked.

I tried creating a Maven project, but the error returned is `no main manifest attribute`. Fixing this error by adding the location of the `Launcher` class to the `MANIFEST.MF` file (`Main-Class: orionindustries.passwordalgorithm.Launcher`) results in a different error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`.

I installed `Inno Setup` to try to create an `exe` file, but I get yet another error: `typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]`.

I tried enabling the `Switch Project to JavaFX Deployment Model` setting under `Deployment` in the Project properties, but it says the `JDK` doesn't support `JavaFX` and doesn't allow me to select any `JDK` when I try to solve it.

I've no idea what else to do. In the previous (now-deleted) question someone mentioned `JDK 14` would come with a packaging tool, but that's not a real solution to my problem, it's just using another tool for something that NetBeans is supposed to be able to do (and even then, there's no guarantee that it'd work). Either I'm screwing up massively, or NetBeans has serious bugs that somehow went unreported.

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial which I co-authored, just to prove that JDK14 with jpackage and some other standard tools does exactly what you need. Forget all the old stuff you have tried so far and which just does not work anymore with modern versions of JavaFX. https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: @mipa I know it's been a month, but a lot of stuff happened and I couldn't really try out your tutorial. Long story short, it didn't create an .exe like it was supposed to. I have WIX installed and set the environment variables (verified with "mvn -version" and "java -version"). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.